# Почему в 11 строке появляется ошибка 'int' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, массивы, списки

Задание: найти строку массива с наименьшим значением суммы всех её элементов и вывести значение суммы и номер строки

```
a = []
j = 5
k = 2
s = 0
m = 100000
for i in range(j):
    for p in range(k):
      a.append(int(input()))
for i in range(j):
    for p in range(k):
        s = s + int(a[i][p])
    if s <= m:
        m = s
        b = i
print(b, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.append(int(input()))` - добавляет целое число в массив, индекс нового элемента `i * j + p`.

`a[i]` - получает целое число из массива.

`a[i][p]` - пытается взять элемент по индексу `p` из целого числа. Не может.

Вероятно, Вы хотели:

```
for i in range(j):
    for p in range(k):
        s = s + int(a[i * j + p])
```

Или

```
for i in range(j):
    a.append([])
    for p in range(k):
        a[i].append(int(input()))
for i in range(j):
    for p in range(k):
        s = s + int(a[i][p])
```

Comment: Как вариант хранить элементы массива как строки, и итерировать по символам, переводя в сохранять результат во временную переменную.

Comment: Тобиш `s = 0 for symb in a[i]: s+=int(symb)` при условии что a.append(input())

Comment: Вопрос: по смыслу - задача о двумерном массиве (строки, столбцы), а по факту - вы работает с явно одномерной структурой и пытаетесь ее самостоятельно интерпретировать через сложный пересчет индексов. Это так задумано? Другими словами - это так хитро сформулировано учебное задание или вот так вы действительно хотите работать с массивами?